# Azure DevOps Pipeline Variables

Tags: azure-pipelines

I've been reading a ton of documentation on Azure Pipelines and I don't get how to access variables between stages. I tried using the stageDependencies but my variable is always blank. Can you help me out with my pipeline please.

I'm trying to pass the hash created on the Prepare stage to the BuildAndDeploy stage but if I look in my Job Preparation parameters is :

```
Variables:
  myHash:
    Parsing expression: <stageDependencies.Prepare.CacheDependencies.outputs['CacheDependencies.CacheDependenciesOutput.pnpmLockHash']>
    Evaluating: stageDependencies['Prepare']['CacheDependencies']['outputs']['CacheDependencies.CacheDependenciesOutput.pnpmLockHash']
    Expanded: Null
    Result: ''
  pnpmLockHash:
    Evaluating: stageDependencies['Prepare']['CacheDependencies']['outputs']['CacheDependencies.CacheDependenciesOutput.pnpmLockHash']
    Expanded: Null
    Result: ''
```

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - pipeline
  paths:
    include:
      - apps/frontend/*

variables:
  - name: projectRoot 
    value: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/apps/frontend
  - name: modifiedProjectsList
    value: ''
  - name: pnpmCachePath
    value: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pnpm-store

stages:
  - stage: Prepare
    displayName: 'Prepare and Cache Dependencies'
    jobs:
      - job: CacheDependencies
        displayName: 'Cache Dependencies'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            submodules: true
            fetchDepth: 2
          - bash: |
              echo "Generating hash for pnpm-lock.yaml..."
              HASH=$(md5sum $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pnpm-lock.yaml | awk '{print $1}')
              echo "My Hash: $HASH"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pnpmLockHash,isOutput=true]$HASH"
            displayName: 'Generate pnpm-lock.yaml Hash'
            name: CacheDependenciesOutput
          - task: Cache@2
            inputs:
              key: 'pnpm | "$(Agent.OS)" | $(pnpmLockHash)'
              restoreKeys: 'pnpm | "$(Agent.OS)"'
              path: $(pnpmCachePath)
              cacheHitVar: CACHE_RESTORED
            displayName: 'Cache pnpm Store'
          - script: |
              echo "Cache Key $(myHash)"
              if [ "$(CACHE_RESTORED)" != "true" ]; then
                echo "Cache miss or change detected, installing dependencies..."
                cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
                pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
                echo "Dependencies installed and cached for future runs."
              else
                echo "Cache hit, using existing pnpm store."
              fi
            displayName: 'Install and Cache Dependencies if not Restored'

  - stage: IdentifyAndSetVariables
    displayName: 'Identify Changes and Set Variables'
    jobs:
      - job: IdentifyChanges
        displayName: 'Identify Changes'
        pool:
          vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            submodules: true
            fetchDepth: 2
          - script: |
              echo "Identifying modified projects..."
              MODIFIED_PROJECTS=$(git diff --name-only HEAD~1 -- 'apps/frontend/*' | awk -F/ '{print $3}' | sort -u | tr '\n' ';')
              MODIFIED_PROJECTS='info-secur'
              IFS=';' read -r -a projectArray <<< "$MODIFIED_PROJECTS"
              for project in "${projectArray[@]}"
              do
                projectName=${project}
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=${projectName}Changed;isOutput=true]true"
              done
            displayName: 'Get the modified projects'
            name: IdentifyChangesOutput

  - stage: BuildAndDeploy
    displayName: 'Build and Deploy Projects'
    dependsOn: [Prepare, IdentifyAndSetVariables]
    condition: succeeded()
    variables:
      - name: myHash
        value: $[stageDependencies.Prepare.CacheDependencies.outputs['CacheDependencies.CacheDependenciesOutput.pnpmLockHash']]

    jobs:
    - job: DeployInfoSecur
      condition: eq(stageDependencies.IdentifyAndSetVariables.IdentifyChanges.outputs['IdentifyChangesOutput.info-securChanged'], 'true')
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      variables:
        - name: pnpmLockHash
          value: $[stageDependencies.Prepare.CacheDependencies.outputs['CacheDependencies.CacheDependenciesOutput.pnpmLockHash']]
      steps:
        - script: |
            echo "Deploying Info-Secur..."
            echo "Cache key: $(pnpmLockHash)"
            echo "Cache Key []:  $(myHash)"
        - template: info-secur-build-deploy.yml
          parameters:
            cacheKey: $(pnpmLockHash)
    - job: DeployGestionAdresses
      condition: eq(stageDependencies.IdentifyAndSetVariables.IdentifyChanges.outputs['IdentifyChangesOutput.gestion-adressesChanged'], 'true')
      pool:
        vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
      steps:
        - script: echo "Deploying Gestion-Adresses..."
        - template: gestion-adresses-build-deploy.yml
```

Thank you for the help.

I want to be able to send the hash variables to my templates but they are always blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a tiny syntax error in your script to generate the output variable value, which is not so easy to find.

The delimiter between `variable=pnpmLockHash` and `isOutput=true` should be a semicolon (`;`), not a comma (`,`).

It is suggested to print the output variable value in the same job before passing it to downstream stages/jobs. Here is the correct syntax for your reference.

```
stages:
  - stage: Prepare
    displayName: 'Prepare and Cache Dependencies'
    jobs:
      - job: CacheDependencies
        displayName: 'Cache Dependencies'
        steps:
          - bash: |
              HASH="xxxxxx"
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=pnpmLockHash;isOutput=true]$HASH"
            displayName: 'Generate pnpm-lock.yaml Hash'
            name: CacheDependenciesOutput
          - script: |
              echo $(CacheDependenciesOutput.pnpmLockHash)
            displayName: Test to print the output variable value
```

Comment: OMG you are a life saver. It's really something I missed I was sure that I checked that. You saved my script thank you so much.